# Movie about teenagers who get abducted by aliens after they enter a house

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

There's this sci-fi movie I'm trying to find. I'm sure it's post 2010.
Here's what I remember:

- Group of teenagers enter a house and lose consciousness.
- They awake somewhere that looks Earth-like.
- One of them appears to have like a mechanical hand that has been surgically attached to his arm. This gives him super strength.
- They try to escape the facility they're being held in.
- Somewhere during the movie (possibly at the end), they break out and discover they're in space on some sort of spaceship.

On Google, I tried several combinations with "teenagers", "alien", "abduction", but for the life of me I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The Signal* (2014).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Signal_(2014_film)):

> Three MIT students – Jonah, Nic, and Haley – are on a road trip to move Haley to California[...]. During their stay in a hotel, Nic and Jonah discover that a hacker named NOMAD, who nearly got them expelled for breaking into MIT servers, has found their location and is taunting them with strange and ominous e-mails. They track NOMAD to an abandoned house in the middle of Nevada and decide to go after him. **After finding nothing in the house, Nic and Jonah hear Haley scream and run outside, only to see her pulled into the sky before disappearing into a white light themselves.** [...]
>
> After hitching a ride with an old lady who seems sweet yet oddly troubled, Nic and Haley hijack an 18-wheeler truck to try to find a way around the seemingly endless canyon that extends around the facility and surrounding area. At a visitors center, they come across Jonah disguised as one of the facility workers dressed in a white hazmat suit. Jonah reveals that he too had limbs taken from him, as **his forearms and hands have been replaced with the same alien technology as Nic's legs.** Jonah speculates that they are in Area 51 (because they both have the same tattooed number, which adds up to 51), and that this is all a test. After Nic discovers indications of alien technology also implanted in Haley's spine, the trio drive up to a military checkpoint [...].
>
> Nic finds himself inside what appears to be a different, larger exterior facility. Housed within it, through the broken barrier, can be seen 'Area 51", the Earth-like world with the canyon city. Looking in through the hole towards the bridge, he sees Damon walk up and remove his helmet to reveal that he is actually a robotic alien, with merely a human-like face. **Nic turns back around, and through the glass sees stars and outer space. He realizes he is not in a government facility, but is actually on an immense alien spacecraft** numbered 2.3.5.41 (matching the numerical tattoo on his arm) that is about to dock at their home world (signaled by the horn).

---

Found by remembering a friend telling me about this movie a couple of years ago. I've never actually seen it myself.

Comment: I saw the movie. The most surreal part was that one lady being played by the investigator from the *Insidious* series, although the whole idea of waking up with your limbs replaced...